# For a continuous group action, is the projection $\pi:M\to M/G$ into the orbit space an open map?

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation

> **Lemma 21.1.**
>   For any continuous action of a topological group $G$ on a topological space $M$, the quotient map $\pi \colon M \to M/G$ is an open map.
>
> *Proof.*
>   For any $g \in G$ and any subset $U \subseteq M$, we define a set $g \cdot U \subseteq M$ by
>   $$
>     g \cdot U
>   = \{ g \cdot x : x \in U \}.
> $$
>   If $U \subseteq M$ is open, then $\pi^{-1}(\pi(U))$ is equal to the union of all sets of the form $g \cdot U$ as $g$ ranges over $G$.
>   Since $p \mapsto g \cdot p$ is a homeomorphism, each such set is open, and therefore $\pi^{-1}(\pi(U))$ is open in $M$.
>   Becaues $\pi$ is a quotient map, this implies that $\pi(U)$ is open in $M/G$, and therefore $\pi$ is an open map.
>
> (Original image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmBbK.jpg).)

I’m having a hard time understanding why $\pi^{-1}\pi(U)$ is the union of $gU$. Isn’t $M/G = \{gU_n\}$ the set of orbits? When you are pulling back to $M$, shouldn’t it be just the point $x$ such that $x \to gx$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\pi^{-1}(\pi(U))$ is the set of $a\in M$ with $\pi(a)\in\pi(U)$. That is
it consists of the $a\in M$ such that $\pi(a)=\pi(b)$ for some $b\in U$.
But $\pi(a)=\pi(b)\iff G\cdot a=G\cdot b\iff a\in G\cdot b\iff a=g\cdot b$
for some $g\in G$. Therefore $a\in\pi^{-1}(\pi (U))$ iff there is $g\in G$
and $b\in U$ with $a=g\cdot b$, that is $\pi^{-1}(\pi(U))=\bigcup_{g\in G}
g\cdot U$.

Comment: Ah I see, so it is just simple group theory after all